# How to sort the data in asc and desc order in table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am new to react js. Here, I am trying to sort the data when the user clicks on the icons.

```
<th scope="col">Technology <i className="fa fa-fw fa-sort sort-icon"></i></th>
```

So, Now I have data which is in the form of an array of objects.

In this, I have 5 columns and sort icon is on every column. So, How do I Implement this thing using the react?

I want to sort using the alphabetical order.

My data looks like,

```
[{
        "id": "5b7d4a566c5fd00507501051",
        "hrmsJdId": null,
        "companyId": null,
        "jdName": "Senior/ Lead UI Developer",
        "jobDescription": null,
        "technology": java,
    }, {
        "id": "5b7fb04d6c5fd004efdb826f",
        "hrmsJdId": null,
        "companyId": null,
        "jdName": "Content Innovation Lead",
        "jobDescription": null,
        "technology": css
    }, {
        "id": "5b7fb0b26c5fd004efdb8271",
        "hrmsJdId": null,
        "companyId": null,
        "jdName": "Urgent Opening for DSP Engineer/ Senior Engineer for",
        "jobDescription": null,
        "technology": react,
    }]

 <td>{item.technology}</td>
                <td>17</td>
                <td title={item.jdName} className="jd-name-container justify-content-center align-items-center">
                  <div className="jdName">{item.jdName}</div>
                  {(key + 1 === 1) && <div className="badge new-badge badge-warning-custom">New</div>}
                </td>
```

This is how I render the data. Now,

By default, I sort it using the

```
   <tbody className="text-center">
          {props.jobList && props.jobList && props.jobList.length > 0 && props.jobList.sort((a, b) => b.createdAt - a.createdAt).map((item, key) => {
            return (
              <tr key={key}>
                <td align="center"> <input type="checkbox" name="myTextEditBox" value="checked" /></td>
                <td>{item.technology}</td>
                <td>17</td>
                <td title={item.jdName} className="jd-name-container justify-content-center align-items-center">
                  <div className="jdName">{item.jdName}</div>
                  {(key + 1 === 1) && <div className="badge new-badge badge-warning-custom">New</div>}
                </td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>
 </tbody>
```

So, How do I implement this ?

What I did is ,

```
<th scope="col">Technology<i className="fa fa-fw fa-sort sort-icon" onClick={props.sortAscending('Technology')}></i></th>
```

then in container

```
    sortData = (key,event) => {
        console.log("key is,", key);
        this.props.sortAscending(key);
      }

<UserJobsTabel jobList={filteredList} sortAscending={this.sortData} />
```

passed as a props.

Now in action,

```
export const sortAscending = (type) => {
  return {
    type: "SORT_ASCENDING",
    payload: type
  }
}
```

In  reducer,

```
case FETCHING_JOBDESCRIPTION_SUCCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                jobList: action.data.jobData ? action.data.jobData.sort((a, b) => b.createdAt - a.createdAt) : action.data.jobData,
                yesterDayScore: action.data.yesterdayScore,
                todayScore: action.data.todayScore,
                error: false,
            }

 case "SORT_ASCENDING": 
          const { sortKey } = action.payload;
            const jobList = [ ...state.jobList ]
        .sort((a, b) => a[sortKey].localeCompare(b[sortKey]));
      return { ...state, jobList };
```

×

```
Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.
```

I am getting this error.

Comment: Do you want to set default value for you sort or want to save your sort in `State`?

Comment: Actually when I get that data then by default I want to set it using the descdendng order .that I do on the basis of the createdDate property. Now, I do it using the prop of created Date./

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`localeCompare()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) to sort in alphabetical order.

Have the sorting done in reducer while the component just dispatches the "sort" action. Every re-sort will cause a component re-render for `jobList` `prop` (in `mapStateToProps`) is updated.

In reducer:

```
const initialState = {
  jobList: [],
};

export const jobList = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case Action.SORT_ALPHA_ASC:
      const { sortKey } = action.payload;
      const jobList = [ ...state.jobList ]
        .sort((a, b) => a[sortKey].localeCompare(b[sortKey]));

      return { ...state, jobList };

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

In your component:

```
// alphaSort will dispatch action: SORT_ALPHA_ASC
const { jobList, alphaSort } = this.props;
if (! jobList || jobList.length < 1) {
  // no job list
  return null;
}

return (
<table>
  <thead>
    { /* TODO: use th/td */ }
    <SomeIcon name='asc-technology' onClick={() => alphaSort('technology')} />
    <SomeIcon name='asc-jdname' onClick={() => alphaSort('jdName')} />
    { /* TODO: other fields */ }
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  {
    jobList.map((job) => ({
      <tr key={job.id}>
        <td name="technology">{job.technology}</td>
        <td title={job.jdName}>
          <div className="jdName">{job.jdName}</div>
        </td>
        { /* TODO: other fields */ }
      </tr>
    }))
  }
  </tbody>
</table>
);
```

**NOTE**:
descending alpha sort and other fields will be for the OP to continue. :)

Comment: So Here I have 5 columns. and the sorting is on each column.

Comment: @ganesh, see updated to use a sort key representing a column.

Comment: That's a good point but I don't think we should create a function to mapping the value of `jobList` from `props` to `state`. This is because this solution will be affect the performance. My solution is when user click on the header, we should `dispatch` an `action` to update the `state` and then write a `selector` to update props

Comment: So Here I was thinking, I will have 3 actions. One which will set the by default state. that means I have to show data as per the last date created. So, First AS soon as I get data I will dispatch one action that will set the data for default .Next On click of the ascending and desc. option I will updated the same data by using the two diff actions.

Comment: @ganesh, yes that's the way to go. three actions: init/fetch, sort asc, sort desc.

Comment: Hey I have updated the question with what I have implemented. Now I am gettting this error.

Comment: When I use a[action.payload] then always I am getting this error that can not read property of null.

Comment: I have used this soultion works fine. But there is only one thing and that is , few columns are having numbers in it. So I also want them to be sorted using same asc or desc.Now, the same logic in reducer will not work here right

Comment: @ganesh, yes. for numbers just sort it by `sort((a, b) => a - b)`. for the original question of sorting alphabetically, please mark this as an answer for it already worked for you. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

React Js arrays have a sort function:

```
['b', 'a'].sort((e1, e2) => e1.id < e2.id  ? 1 : - 1)
```

If the lambda function returns 0, it does nothing. Otherwise, the two elements in the array will be sorted by the sign of the returned value.

If there are duplicate IDs in the database then the function will return 0.

To swap the order, change either the sign of the return value or the "smaller than" operator to a greater than operator.